# Sharing a variable from main to another c file

Tags: c

I have a function

```
int InsertToList(List **head,......,char *FileName);
```

And this function is implemented in Source1.c

However this FileName string is taken from command line arguments and its declared  inside the main function in Main.c of the same project

I was wondering how can I have the FileName string in InsertToList function without passing it to its arguments and also without using global variables?

What I mean is:

```
int InsertToList(List **head,......)
{
   File *fp;
   fp = fopen(FileName,"r"); // here FileName is passed from the main in Main.c
   doSomething();
}
```

Comment: @RSahu, how would that not be using a global variable, which the OP says he doesn't want to do?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I missed that.

Comment: If you mean inside the same `.c` file, you could make it a `static` variable, and no other module would be able to link to it.   It's still considered just about as much bad form as a true global variable though.

Comment: Why don't you want to pass it as an argument? This is a perfect use of arguments.

Comment: Well, al long are we're bending over backwards to do it, let's assume a Linux `/proc` filesystem, and let `InsertToList` reparse the command line arguments  from `/proc/NNN/cmdline` where NNN is the process ID number

Answer (score 1):

> And i was wondering how can i have the FileName string in InsertToList function without passing it to its arguments and also without using global variables.

1. Create a file scoped `static` variable in `main.c`.
2. Set the value in `main.c`.
3. Provide a function in `main.c` to return that value.
4. Use the function from `InsertToList`.

---

main.c

```
static char* fileName;
char* getFileName()
{
   return fileName;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    fileName = ...;
}
```

Source1.c:

```
// Provide a declaration of the function that's defined in main.c.
char* getFileName();

int InsertToList(List **head,...)
{
   File *fp;
   fp = fopen(getFileName(),"r");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.this will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can not. If you want the functions to have shared state, you either have to pass it in via the call arguments or you have to access a shared symbol, in other words a global variable.

This is true even for functions in the same file.

Comment: There are possible but silly ways to do it.  Write the string to a file, and make the subroutine read that file.  Open some IPC shared memory would be another.  I'm certain there are plenty of rube-Goldberg ways to do it.  But why!

Comment: @infixed why indeed. And all those fancy ways boil down to some kind of shared symbol: file name, IPC token, ... global state.

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of ways to communicate data between functions, but global variables and function parameters are the two primary ones.  For functions whose bodies appear in the same source file there are also `static` file-scope variables, which are not exactly *global*, but have similar flavor; this does not apply to the case you describe, however.

I can understand wanting to avoid global variables, and in fact I commend you for that, but also avoiding function arguments for the purpose is ... odd.  @RSahu suggests using a `static` variable with accessor function; if you consider a `static` file-scope variable different from a global and therefore allowable, then this is perhaps your best option.  Otherwise, your options are things like one function writing the data to a file with a well-known name, and the other function reading it back from there.  Most such alternatives are much worse than global variables.

If you have multiple threads or multiple processes then a pipe might be a viable option, but you don't say anything to suggest that that is the situation.

If you simply want to *minimize* the number of function parameters then consider defining a `struct` type with members for all the data you want to exchange, and passing such a struct, or a pointer to one, as the function parameter.

Comment: the reason is that i have alot of source files and functions in this project but i can use only one function inside the main function.

This function will then pass the arguments tooked by command line to other functions in rest .c files.


However the problem is that the FileName string is being passed "unnecessarily several times to alot of functions which realted to each other, so ïts finally get to the last function in which it will be used.


I can make changes so only the last function will use the FileName string but this wil make me change the whole code unfortunally.